# CSS submit button width incorrect

Tags: html, css

I have an input (type="submit") as a button, and it should just be as wide/high as the text plus the padding. This has worked with previous buttons I have done, but now it doesn't seem to work. The button text displays as two lines, but it should only be displaying as one.

```css
.account-container.edit,
.information,
input.account-save {
  width: fit-content;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 2% 6%;
  color: white;
  background-color: #55ad47;
  border-radius: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  resize: auto;
  line-height: normal;
  display: block;
}

.account-container.edit,
.information,
input,
textarea {
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  border: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Myriad Pro, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  outline-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="account-save" value="Save Profile">
```

The strange thing is that if you inspect element and toggle any of the dimension parameters of the button, it "fixes" itself and changes to the dimensions it should be:

[image: Before]

It should look like this (and does after toggling width etc.)

[image: After]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: You're using the 'fit-content' wrong, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#fit-content

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `fit-content` fallbacks for older browsers:

```
width: -webkit-fit-content;
width: -moz-fit-content;
width: fit-content;
```

IE does not support the property at all. [mdn-fit-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)

According to [mdn-resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/resize) there is no `auto` value for `resize`. You might want to choose something valid here.

Other than that it looks okay. You may want to tell us, what browsers you did the tests on so that I (or someone else) can test it properly.

I have tested it to be good looking on:

- Firefox 77.01
- Safari 13.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I worked out that I was setting my padding as a percent, which was calculated as a percent of the whole screen / parent container, and not of the "fit-content" size of the input. Therefore, the input was the right size for the text, but the padding was shifting the text over off-axis, and the full size of the button was not calculated to include the padding.

(the size of the padding was calculated after the size of the input was calculated, and a toggle of the dimensions in "inspect element" was recalculating the size of the input, this time accounting for the padding, which was previously assumed to be 0)

Answer (score 0):

I added white-space: break-spaces; and now the value, what people see in the button,  wraps nicely with the suggestions above. Check your line-height too.